# Render method returns null in react router v4

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux, redux-router

I'm trying to implement a private route with react-router v4 and redux, but the render prop returns null for some reason. I'd be very grateful if someone helps me figure out what is wrong.
Router:

```
const router = (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter history={history}>
              <App>
                <Route exact path="/" component={UserGrid}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route exact path="/users/:userId" component={UserPage}/>
                <Route path="/registration" component={RegistrationPage}/>
                <TopSecretRoute path="/topSecret" component={SecretComponent}/>
              </App>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </Provider>
```

TopSecretRoute.js:

```
const TopSecretRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    props.session.registered ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

const stateToProps = ['session']
export default createContainer(stateToProps,TopSecretRoute)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably facing the problem React Router have with [Update Blocking](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking). This happens because Redux avoids re-renders and call mapStateToProps, instead.

To prevent this behavior your can pass the option `pure: false` in react-redux connect function.

Example:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false })(Component);
```

You can head to [React Redux API documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) to see more details on this option.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that, gonna read up on it later. I fixed the issue by removing TopSecretRoute component and encapsulating the behaviour I needed in a higher-order-component, which is also an option.

Comment: Yeah, there are more than one way to fix that. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate you can use `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
.
.
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AppRoutes));
```

References-

1. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671
2. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter